Fetching rows containing highest value, and previous highest in SQL
Example table:



User
Updated
Item
Status




Bob
1.4
Apple
Eaten


Bob
1.4
Orange
Moldy


Bob
1.3
Apple
Ripe


Bob
1.2
Apple
New


Bob
1.1
Orange
Ripe


Bob
1.0
Banana
New



I want to be able to search based on a given Updated value and fetch each unique User/Item row matching the given value, as well as the next highest Updated row, in order to track historical changes in Item values.
If there is only one row, don't return it.
For example, doing a search for Bob and 1.4 should return:



User
Updated
Item
Status




Bob
1.4
Apple
Eaten


Bob
1.3
Apple
Ripe


Bob
1.4
Orange
Moldy


Bob
1.1
Orange
Ripe



Here, the matching Updated rows (1.4) for both Apple and Orange are included, as well as the next closest row (1.3 and 1.1 respectively).
This is where I'm having issues; if it was simply to return matching Updated and Updated-0.1 the query would be straightforward, but I'm looking for the next highest Updated column match for each.

It seems that the item column also plays some role in the results, but that's not explained in the question.

I'll edit the question for clarification.

WITH RankedUpdates AS (
    SELECT 
        User, 
        Updated, 
        Item, 
        Status,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY Updated DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        YourTableName
    WHERE 
        User = 'Bob' AND Updated <= 1.4
)

SELECT * 
FROM RankedUpdates
WHERE rn <= 2  -- Get the current and the next highest
ORDER BY Updated DESC;

Output:



User
Updated
Item
Status




Bob
1.4
Apple
Eaten


Bob
1.4
Orange
Moldy


Bob
1.3
Apple
Ripe




Please provide an explanation of your answer.
